# prevent parent window refreshes on child open

Tags: javascript, html

I haven function that opens child window. However I am returning false, the parent window is getting refresh. I have return false statement, but it never gets executed because control goes to child window.

```
function openChild()
{
  childWindow = window.open('' + child_url + '', 'XREF_topic_product_ADD', 'scrollbars=1, statusbar=1, resizable=1, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, height=250, width=800');
   childWindow.focus();
    return false;
}

<a id="addTopicProduct" href="#" onclick="openChild();return false;" >Add Topic Product</a>
```

Comment: Do you see `#` appended to the URL in the address bar of the parent window? How far down in the page is the link you're clicking? And what do you mean when you say the window "refreshes": is the page reloading by triggering a new request or resetting itself back to the top of the document? The latter hints at my very first question regarding the URL.

Comment: The page refresh = reloading all element of parent element as well as making ajax call whatever I have defined in parent.

Comment: My guess is that there's another javascript error on the page. What you have works fine here (obviously replacing child_url): http://jsfiddle.net/A6Ves/1/

Comment: Once window is open, the debugger does not goes to next line to return false. I am not seeing any error in firebug, chrome, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the "#" try with something simple like, change your  (anchor) to :

```
<a id="addTopicProduct" href="#openwindow"  title="open window" onclick="openChild();return false;" >Add Topic Product</a>
```

Comment: Sorry

EDIT :
<a id="addTopicProduct" href="#openwindow"  title="openwindow" onclick="openChild();return false;" >Add Topic Product</a>